# find the value at kth position when numbers are sorted lexicographically till n

Tags: math, c++

Ex :-
Input:
n = 12, k = 5

Output:
ans = 2

Sorted list S: ["1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3", "4", "5", ...., "9"]
ans =  2

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This site is for recreational programming puzzles, not programming help. If you intend this as a proper challenge, you'll have to add a objective winning criteria (e.g. [tag:code-golf]) , remove the [tag:c++] tag and make it sound a lot less like "I want help with my homework"

Comment: I think that this could be a good question for code-golf, provided that it isn't a duplicate. There are two remarks however, and both of them are that index-related. Since you say that you use C++ (which is 0-indexed), why are your numbers 1-12 rather than 0-11, and why is the answer `a[4]` if `5` is the input? Also, `╒░s\(§` and `╒░s§` are solutions in MathGolf for the original problem and a 0-indexed version.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 55 bytes

```
(n,i)=>+[...Array(n).keys()].map(x=>x+1+"").sort()[i-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsMgEIXhfY@R1QyaAQNdFQMlxwhZTKwptiaKhpKc3rpvt9/Pey/@cDbJxb3dwsOWsmjYpEPdi5GI7inxCapDetszA060coRD94dQommQckg7AMu5Lph8MOztENbIycKMOLpWTcWELQdva37CUt/kFfF2@VH1X7vK5Qs)

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, so I'll include it in my answer:

Welcome to PPCG! To make this a challenge you have to clarify some requirements of the challenge. Add a proper description, define the expected output and the winning criteria and also add some example tests.

Comment: The default sort in javascript is lexicographic.  So you can write `.sort()` instead of `.sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))`

Comment: @Spitemaster well, yea. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 32 bytes

```r
function(n,k)sort(c(1:n,"x"))[k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTydbszi/qEQjWcPQKk9HqUJJUzM6O/Z/moahkY6p5n8A)